# Where did the Genesis planet's sunlight come from?

Tags: star-trek

Towards the end of *Wrath of Khan*, the Genesis torpedo explodes and creates a planet from the material of the planetary nebula in which the Enterprise and the Reliant fought each other.

I went to Google to look up why the Genesis planet was receiving a glow of natural sunlight from... somewhere, when all the matter of the nebula was consumed and used as material to create the planet.

There is already a question discussing where the light in the Genesis cave earlier in the movie came from. But I don't think what happened in the Genesis cave could magically occur in outer space. I read that "the cave glowed from inside", which is not how planets work.

Did the Genesis torpedo create a star as well as the planet, was there an existing star just happening to be at the right spot, or where else did the sunlight on the planet come from?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This reads more like a comment than a question; you should clean this up to ask a single, clear question.  Perhaps you want to ask "what was the star of the Genesis planet?"

Comment: Note that this too is answered in the accepted answer on the duplicate: "A world has formed; the Genesis wave is still resonating within the nebula, forming a new sun to give the world light and sustain its life."

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I managed to overlook that.

Comment: I always assumed the planetoid in which the Genesis cave was located was already orbiting a star. It had day and night sides, right, and wasn't floating through space?